# 10G Upgrade - SuperMicro Server keeps freezing on load

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, freeze

OK, I am trying to upgrade a SuperMicro server with an ASUS 10G NIC that was flashed to the latest firmware on both cards for Windows & Linux (Server).  Windows is working fine, but Linux keeps freezing the entire system after short usage.  I have to power cycle to get it back and then it takes less and less time to freeze (overheating??).  I don't know how to check.

**Question:**

Has anyone gotten the ASUS XG-C100C 10G to work reliably on Linux Ubuntu 20.04?

Built the driver from Marvel (latest), I am wondering if there are properties to change and where to change them? (maybe buffers, etc. to fix the problem.)  One thing I like about Windows are the preferences/properties.  Where do I find this information?

Thanks.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

> Have to power cycle to get back and then it takes less and less time to freeze (overheating??) Don't know how to check.

Install lm-sensors:

```bsh
sudo apt install lm-sensors
```

Detect sensors and view them:

```bsh
sudo sensors-detect
sensors
```

> Don't know how to check.

Check `dmesg` for anything unusual, most importantly for kernel OOPs.

> Built driver from Marvel (latest), wondering if there are properties to change and where to change them??, maybe buffers, etc. to fix the problem.

If you're absolutely sure the drivers are of the latest version, please try to contact the vendor directly. There's little help people here can offer.